# How can I un-hide the run button on the top right corner of the vs-code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have been using vs-code version 1.72.2. And I have mistakenly hidden the run button on the top right corner of the vs-code editor, while working on a python file. Now, I cannot find a way to unhide it. Is there any way to do this? Please, help me out.

Comment: Try right-clicking on some nearby icon or the 3 dots and see if there is an option to re-enable it.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the `...` in the same top right toolbar area, then click 'Reset Menu'

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_72#_hide-actions-from-tool-bars

Answer (score 0):

Some extensions may cause this. The problem can be solved by disabling the extension that causes the problem, or it can be made visible again from the settings depending on the programming language used.

For example C/C++:

Go to File > Preferences > Settings and type "Debug Shortcut" in the search bar above and check the "C_Cpp: Debug Shortcut" box in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Go to view, click run, and left-click on the run and debug icon on the left side. Next, click on "Keep Run and Debug" and it will stay. i hope this is what you meant